# Avoid duplicate outputs in text files using java?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have a simple problem.

I have a text file which has records like this:

```
HAMADA 115599
KARIM 224466
BOSY 47896512
```

this file actually defines the username and password for user accounts

now i wrote a simple code to edit password of a specific user.

here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test6 {
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

String newPassword=null;
boolean checked = true;

File f= new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\accounts.txt");// path to your file
File tempFile = new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\accounts2.txt"); // create a temp file in same path
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
System.out.println("Change account password !!");
System.out.println("Validate your account please !!");
System.out.printf("Username: ");
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
String username = sc2.next().toUpperCase();
System.out.printf("Old Password: ");
String password = sc2.next();
while(sc.hasNextLine())
{
String currentLine= sc.nextLine();
String[] tokens = currentLine.split(" ");
if(Objects.equals(tokens[0], username) && Objects.equals(tokens[1], password) && checked)
{
     sc2.nextLine();                          
     System.out.printf("New Password: ");
     newPassword= sc2.nextLine();
     if(newPassword.length() >= 6)
     {
     currentLine = tokens[0]+" "+newPassword;
     checked = false;
     }
     else
         System.out.println("Short Password, Password must be at least 6 characters.");
 }
    else{System.out.println("Wrong username or password .. try again !!");}
 writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

 }
 writer.close(); 
 sc.close();
 f.delete();
 boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(f);
 if(successful == true)
 System.out.println("Your password has been changed successfully.");
 else
 System.out.println("Error occurred during changing password, please try again.");

 }
 }
```

the problem is: if i have many records in the file as mentioned above, now it will write the message "Wrong username or password" for every record stops at it. i just want to make program say this message only on the entered record that not found in the file then program stops. and if record was found in the file then it allows user to change password of that record

Comment: "program crashes" ? what is the exact exception you are getting ?

Comment: just run the program to understand what is happening.

Comment: well sorry bro if my question is not defined well, when i run this program every time i search for a record it writes "Wrong username or password try again" .... and this can be showed while editing password itself, this what i mean by crashing ... the program is not written well. first i search for userame and password that i want to edit password for it, if it founds then it allows me to change, it not then it show this message. but as you see it writes this message everywhere in the program .

Comment: So what did you learn when you stepped through the code in your debugger?

Comment: post edited, you can see my problem, i will explain problem again. the message "wrong username or password" must be showed only when a user account is not found, but when i enter a username and password that are exists ... it searches in every line in the file and write the message for every line that not found the record in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to write "wrong username or password" is inside your `while` loop, so it gets called for every line in the file that does not match the current search parameters. To fix this, move the error message outside of the `while` loop so that it can only be called once.

These errors are very easy to spot in properly indented code, because it then becomes obvious what is inside the loop and what is not. In general, use proper formatting to make debugging easier.

**Edit:** For instance, you could do this:

```
// Open the file...
boolean found = false;
while(sc.hasNextLine())
{
    // Read the line...
    if (Objects.equals(tokens[0], username) && Objects.equals(tokens[1], password) && checked)
    {
        // Do stuff...
        found = true;
        break; // Done looking
    }
}
if (!found)
{
    System.out.println("Wrong username or password .. try again !!");
}
// Close the file...
```

Comment: I know that the problem is at while loop but how to get it outside, this is the question.

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer The easiest way is to set `boolean found = false;` before the while loop, and then set `found = true;` when the search term is found.

Comment: please can you write this code for me, Iam understanding you but i failed to do this.

Comment: @BeginnerProgrammer I've given you an outline, but remember, StackOverlfow is not a code-writing service. We'll help you find solutions, but you should implement them yourself.

Comment: yes i know StackOverflow, i write the code myself, i just was stuck in this question only and you get me the solution :)